# how to return or read a negative signed byte value in rax in nasm x86?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, signed

I compare 2 bytes of 2 strings which pointers are stored in `rdi` and `rsi`. First I copy the data into `al` and `bl` and then store the difference in `al` and returning it if not zero

```
section .text
    global  ft_strcmp
increment:
    inc rdi
    inc rsi
    jmp ft_strcmp
ft_strcmp:
    mov al, byte[rdi]
    mov bl, byte[rsi]
    sub al, bl
    cmp al, 0
    jz increment
    ret
```

When the difference is possitive, it returns the right number, but when `al` is negative, the complete register `rax` takes it as an unsigned value, returning 255 instead of -1 (comparing for example 'a' - 'b'); 254 instead of -2 ('a' - 'c') and so on.

How to tell the `rax` register to read the byte data as signed?

Comment: It is unlikely you want a 64 bit result. But if you do, you can `movsx rax, al` PS: you don't need the `cmp al, 0` as `sub al, bl` already sets flags. Also you do not need to load into `bl` you can use a memory operand. Especially since `rbx` should be preserved according to convention. The `jmp ft_strcmp` is useless since it jumps to the next instruction.

Comment: Then how can I return from the function ft_strcmp? The returned value is in rax, and It should be a signed int result of the difference which i think will be a byte sized

Comment: Sign extending the result of an 8-bit subtraction won't work; consider what happens if `al` is 254 and `bl` is 1.  You should load them zero-extended and then do a 32-bit subtract, e.g. `movzx eax, byte[rdi] / movzx ecx, byte[rsi] / sub eax, ecx / jz increment`.  Then `eax` contains the signed result you want.

Comment: By the way, you have another bug in that if the strings are identical, you will overrun them.  You need to check whether you have encountered a null byte.

Comment: Normally a strcmp implementation will run until it finds the position of a difference, *then* sign-extend both bytes and subtract them.  You can just use efficient `movzx eax, byte [rdi]` / `cmp al, [rsi]` inside the loop.  (And also `test eax,eax` after that as the loop condition, to stop if this was the last byte.)